# Selenoid query priority

Tags: pytest, selenoid

There is a question: Is there a possibility to set tests to perform priority in selenoid.

Problem: There is a suite> 20 tests, correspondingly at startup it fills the queue. After that, another test is run. He gets to the end of the line.

Is there an option to make it run as soon as the browser is freed, without waiting for all the tests to run before it?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible in current implementation. All incoming requests have equal priority. Two alternatives:

1. I think such issues should be addressed in test framework of you choice. For example for `py.test` a quick search shows a plugin for ordering your tests: https://github.com/ftobia/pytest-ordering Not sure whether it works.
2. You could also install [Ggr](http://github.com/aerokube/ggr/) and use different Selenoids and quota names for different tests, but this seems to be too much complicated for your case.